Infinite loop trying to navigate maze using Rule Based AI
I'm creating a Rule Based AI that can solve a maze. It should be able to remember where it's been so if it reaches a dead end it can go back on itself and know to use a different rule when it reaches a previously visited cell.
Here are my rules:
from def_solver import *
from def_maze_entry_point import maze

class Rule:

    def __init__(self, condition, action):
        self.condition = condition
        self.action = action

    def matches(self, state):
        return self.condition(state)

    def execute(self, state):
        return self.action(state)
    

def can_move_right(state):
    x, y, _maze = state
    return y + 1 < len(_maze[0]) and _maze[x][y + 1] == 0

    
def move_right(state):
    x, y, maze = state
    return (x, y+1, maze)
    
def can_move_left(state):
    x, y, maze = state
    return y - 1 >= 0 and maze[x][y-1] == 0
    
def move_left(state):
    x, y, maze = state
    return (x, y-1, maze)

def can_move_up(state):
    x, y, maze = state
    return x - 1 >= 0 and maze[x-1][y] == 0

def move_up(state):
    x, y, maze = state
    return (x-1, y, maze)

def can_move_down(state):
    x, y, maze = state
    return x + 1 < len(maze) and maze[x+1][y] == 0

def move_down(state):
    x, y, maze = state
    return (x+1, y, maze)


def is_goal(state, goal):
    x, y, _ = state
    a, b, _ = goal
    if (x,y) == (a,b):
        return True
    else:
        return False

And here is my maze solver:
from def_rules import Rule, can_move_right, move_right, can_move_down, move_down, can_move_up, move_up, can_move_left, move_left
from def_maze_entry_point import maze
from def_rules import is_goal

class Solver:
    def __init__(self):
        self.visitedCellsAndRuleUsed = {}
        self.maze = maze
        
        start_x, start_y = 0, 0
        self.initial_state = (start_x, start_y, self.maze)  
        goal_x, goal_y = 4, 5
        self.goal_state = (goal_x, goal_y, self.maze) 
        self.current_state = self.initial_state

        self.ruleStack = [
            Rule(condition=can_move_right, action=move_right),
            Rule(condition=can_move_down, action=move_down),
            Rule(condition=can_move_up, action=move_up),
            Rule(condition=can_move_left, action=move_left)
        ]
    
    def is_visited(self, state):
        x, y, _ = state  
        return (x, y) in self.visitedCellsAndRuleUsed

    def mark_visited(self, state, rule):
        x, y, _ = state  
        self.visitedCellsAndRuleUsed[(x, y)] = rule

    def apply_rules(self):
        for rule in self.ruleStack:
            if rule.condition(self.current_state):
                print(f"Applying rule: {rule.condition.__name__}")
                next_state = rule.action(self.current_state)
                print(f"Next state after applying {rule.condition.__name__}: {next_state}")
                return rule, next_state
        return None, None  # No valid rule found
    
    def solve_maze(self):
        i = 0
        while True and i < 15:
            i += 1
            print("Current state: (x={}, y={})".format(self.current_state[1], self.current_state[0]))
            print("Visited Cells: ", self.visitedCellsAndRuleUsed)
            if is_goal(self.current_state, self.goal_state):
                print("Maze Complete!")
                break
            
            rule, next_state = self.apply_rules()
           
            if rule is not None and next_state is not None:
                if not self.is_visited(next_state):
                    self.mark_visited(next_state, rule)
                    print("Applied Rule: {} -> Next state: (x={}, y={})".format(rule.action.__name__,       next_state[1], next_state[0]))
                    self.current_state = next_state
                    print("The Rule used is: ", rule.action.__name__)
                else:
                    print("Next state ({}->{}) already visited.".format(next_state[1], next_state[0]))
                    x, y, _ = next_state
                    last_rule_used = self.visitedCellsAndRuleUsed[(x,y)]
                    print("Last rule used at ({}, {}): {}".format(x, y, last_rule_used.action.__name__))
                    
                    last_rule_index = self.ruleStack.index(last_rule_used)
                    self.ruleStack = self.ruleStack[last_rule_index+1:] + self.ruleStack[:last_rule_index+1]
                    print("Updated ruleStack:", [rule.action.__name__ for rule in self.ruleStack])
                    continue

And here is the maze it is trying to solve, (0,0) is the start and (4,5) is the goal. 1's are obstacles:
maze = [
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]

When I run this, it starts off well by going right, realising that it is a dead end it goes back on itself and then going down. But then when it reaches (0,4) it gets stuck in an infinite loop. It should use the move_right rule but it doesn't. Why not?
Here is the output when I run it:
Current state: (x=0, y=0)
Visited Cells:  {}
Applying rule: can_move_right
Next state after applying can_move_right: (0, 1, [[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
Applied Rule: move_right -> Next state: (x=1, y=0)
The Rule used is:  move_right
Current state: (x=1, y=0)
Visited Cells:  {(0, 1): <def_rules.Rule object at 0x0000017AA3B8A540>}
Applying rule: can_move_left
Next state after applying can_move_left: (0, 0, [[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
Applied Rule: move_left -> Next state: (x=0, y=0)
The Rule used is:  move_left
Current state: (x=0, y=0)
Visited Cells:  {(0, 1): <def_rules.Rule object at 0x0000017AA3B8A540>, (0, 0): <def_rules.Rule object at 0x0000017AA3B8AB40>}
Applying rule: can_move_right
Next state after applying can_move_right: (0, 1, [[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
Next state (1->0) already visited.
Last rule used at (0, 1): move_right
Updated ruleStack: ['move_down', 'move_up', 'move_left', 'move_right']
Current state: (x=0, y=0)
Visited Cells:  {(0, 1): <def_rules.Rule object at 0x0000017AA3B8A540>, (0, 0): <def_rules.Rule object at 0x0000017AA3B8AB40>}
Applying rule: can_move_down
Next state after applying can_move_down: (1, 0, [[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
Applied Rule: move_down -> Next state: (x=0, y=1)
The Rule used is:  move_down
Current state: (x=0, y=1)
Visited Cells:  {(0, 1): <def_rules.Rule object at 0x0000017AA3B8A540>, (0, 0): <def_rules.Rule object at 0x0000017AA3B8AB40>, (1, 0): <def_rules.Rule object at 0x0000017AA3B8A960>}
Applying rule: can_move_down
Next state after applying can_move_down: (2, 0, [[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
Applied Rule: move_down -> Next state: (x=0, y=2)
The Rule used is:  move_down
Current state: (x=0, y=2)
Visited Cells:  {(0, 1): <def_rules.Rule object at 0x0000017AA3B8A540>, (0, 0): <def_rules.Rule object at 0x0000017AA3B8AB40>, (1, 0): <def_rules.Rule object at 0x0000017AA3B8A960>, (2, 0): <def_rules.Rule object at 0x0000017AA3B8A960>}
Applying rule: can_move_down
Next state after applying can_move_down: (3, 0, [[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
Applied Rule: move_down -> Next state: (x=0, y=3)
The Rule used is:  move_down
Current state: (x=0, y=3)
Visited Cells:  {(0, 1): <def_rules.Rule object at 0x0000017AA3B8A540>, (0, 0): <def_rules.Rule object at 0x0000017AA3B8AB40>, (1, 0): <def_rules.Rule object at 0x0000017AA3B8A960>, (2, 0): <def_rules.Rule object at 0x0000017AA3B8A960>, (3, 0): <def_rules.Rule object at 0x0000017AA3B8A960>}
Applying rule: can_move_down
Next state after applying can_move_down: (4, 0, [[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
Applied Rule: move_down -> Next state: (x=0, y=4)
The Rule used is:  move_down
Current state: (x=0, y=4)
Visited Cells:  {(0, 1): <def_rules.Rule object at 0x0000017AA3B8A540>, (0, 0): <def_rules.Rule object at 0x0000017AA3B8AB40>, (1, 0): <def_rules.Rule object at 0x0000017AA3B8A960>, (2, 0): <def_rules.Rule object at 0x0000017AA3B8A960>, (3, 0): <def_rules.Rule object at 0x0000017AA3B8A960>, (4, 0): <def_rules.Rule object at 0x0000017AA3B8A960>}
Applying rule: can_move_up
Next state after applying can_move_up: (3, 0, [[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
Next state (0->3) already visited.
Last rule used at (3, 0): move_down
Updated ruleStack: ['move_up', 'move_left', 'move_right', 'move_down']
Current state: (x=0, y=4)

